# Umbraco throwing 404

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, umbraco

I have an umbraco 4 site that I have put a google sitemap onto.  This all works fine locally but on the live server I am getting an IIS 404 error (not the umbraco 404 error) - [see this link](http://www.fmg.co.uk/fmg-corporate-sitemap/).

However if I preview the node it works fine

I have googled why I would get a 404 and so far I have come up with the following causes which I have checked and can rule out as the cause:

- the template is not assigned
- there are multiple nodes with the same url

Would anyone know what is causing this problem or how I could fix it?

**Update**

I have deleted the preview node now as I recreated the node in a different place and it worked.  Would still like any thoughts on why I would get a 404 though, just in case a similar thing happens in future

Comment: Are you sure that's an Umbraco v4 site? I seem to remember it being built in v5 :)

Comment: Also, are you sure the page has been published on the live site? The site looks like it is not displaying the Umbraco 404 page for any incorrect URLs.

Comment: @Digbyswift it was built in 5 until I came in and realised v5 was a pile of steaming poo so I rebuilt it.  I never solved the problem but recreated the page under a different node and it worked so not sure what was causing it

Comment: I'm glad it got rebuilt, but then the client was adamant they wanted v5 at the time. Is there a reason you didn't use v6?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately both your links are going to the IIS error page as well as all the other errors on the site so we cant tell what you sitemap should be, see this link for tips on how to set up the 404 page http://www.simonantony.net/knowledge-base/articles/how-to-setup-a-404-error-page-on-your-umbraco-site/ .

Make sure that's working across the whole site then with you Google site map is it an XML sitemap or HTML sitemap and how have you implemented it did you use a package or made it you self.

Comment: -1 Sorry, this is not an answer to the OP. He is not asking how to set up 404 pages.